# How to increment the previous value in a map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using the std::map data structure in C++ and I'm trying to increment the value at a certain position each time.

If I understand the `map` has a **key** and a **value** associated with that specific key.

So I'm iterating over an `array` that has unique integers stored inside him.

What I was trying to do is that as I was iterating over the array, pass the value stored in that specific index of the array as a **key** to my map.

For example:

```
std::map<int, int> my_map;
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
{
    my_map.insert(array[i], ...); // the ... part is supposed to be the increment
}
```

I was thinking to pass `++my_map[array[i]]`. I haven't tried that cause I currently don't have access to my Laptop. It's just an idea I just came up with while I'm not home and I wanted to ask to be sure.

Also if `my_map[array[i]]` is valid I would like to use it as an if statement inside my loop:

```
std::map<int, int> my_map;
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
{
    // set the initial value to 0 if the element doesn't exist in the map
    // else increment the previous value by one
    if(!my_map.find(array[i]))
    {
       my_map.insert(array[i], 0);
    }
    else
    {
       my_map.insert(array[i], ++my_map[array[i]]);
    }
}
```

If I have things wrong in my head please correct me. I hope that I translated my problem good enough for you to understand it. Thank you all!

**Edit**:
As I said in the comments the correct code is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
{
    // set the initial value to 0 if the element doesn't exist in the map
    // else increment the previous value by one
    if(!(my_map.count(array[i])))
    {
        my_map.insert(std::pair<int,int>(array[i], 0));
    }
    else
    {
        my_map.insert(std::pair<int,int>(array[i], ++my_map[array[i]]));
    }
}
```

Again thank you all!!!

Comment: I suggest you first try it yourself: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Yeah I will use it for multiple arrays with the same functionality. Sorry forgot to mention it. @churill

Comment: Also I will try it right now @Evg .

Comment: So I shouldn't use `.find` I think I need `.count`.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand ;) Note that you can always [edit] your question. I think `++my_map[array[i]]` is exactly what you want. If the key doesn't exists it's created with value `0`, after this the value is incremented by one.

Comment: I tried it and there are some problems with my code:

Firstly should use `.count`
Secondly this `my_map.insert(array[i], ++my_map[array[i]]);` this is incorrect syntax.

Should change to this `my_map.insert(std::pair<int,int>(array2[i], ++my_map[array2[i]]));`

This now works!
Thank you all and Evg thank you for suggesting to try it. For some reason I forgot about online compilers.

Comment: In place of `my_map.insert(array[i], ++my_map[array[i]])`, write just plain `++my_map[array[i]]` . You are overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(my_map.find(array[i])==my_map.end()){//YOU CAN ALSO USE stl function count
      my_map.insert(make_pair(array[i], 0));
   }else{
      my_map.insert(make_pair(array[i], ++my_map[array[i]]));
   }
   OR:
   if(my_map.find(array[i])==my_map.end()){
      my_map[array[i]]=0;
   }else{
      my_map[arr[i]]++;
   }
```

Comment: Your if statement checks if the item is there and inserts a 0 it if does which I think is backwards, isn't it?